# Call function that has been defined within a function

Tags: python, function, call

Here is my code:

```
def function1():
    def function2():
        print 'function2 has been called'
    def function3():
        pass
```

function1 allows me to call function2 and function3 in a sequence.
But how can I call function2 or function3 from outside of function1?

I tried without success:

```
function1.function2()
```

and:

```
import function1
function1.function2()
```

Comment: That's not possible. Move the function outside of `function1` if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call the nested functions. They are local to `function1()` only.

Either move their definition *out* of `function1()` to make them global names, call them inside of `function1()`, or return them so that anyone calling `function1()` can obtain references to the function objects.

Function objects inside another function are like any other local variable, private to the function only.

As globals:

```
def function2():
    print 'function2 has been called'

def function3():
    pass

def function1():
    # call the other functions
    function2()
    function3()
```

Comment: So there is no way to set them as global functions?

Comment: @MoTSCHIGGE: Sure there is, make them global functions. Why do you *have* to nest them?

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters: Because this allows me to call the inner functions at once.
What is the syntax to make them global functions?

global function2 doesnt work

Comment: You can call *any* global function at once. You don't need to make them inner functions *at all*.

Comment: Right, but in this case function2 and 3 have to be declared prior to function1. I wanted to avoid this to to make the code easier to read.
But I think the only way to avoid it is to use classes and their methods.

Comment: @MoTSCHIGGE They can be declared in any order as long as the call to `function1()` is after they've all been declared

Comment: @MoTSCHIGGE: No, they need to be declared before you *call* `function1()`. You can define them after `function1()` has been defined just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you need function2 and function3 to be inner functions (because they use variables local to function1 but are not passed in as arguments to f2 or f3, or some other reason), write a function that returns a function.

The function:

```
def function1(a,b):
    c = a+b
    d = a*b*c
    def function2(d):
        print c+d
    def function3():
        pass
    function2(d)
```

is equivalent to:

```
def funcwrap(c):
    def inner(d):
        return c+d
    return inner

def function1(a,b):
    c = a+b
    d = a*b*c
    function2 = funcwrap(c)
    print function2(d)
```

This allows you to create and use function2 both inside and outside of function1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create module can be class

```
class MySuperClass:
    def function2(self):
        print 'function2 has been called'
    def function3(self, someArg):
        print 'function3 has been called with argument: '+ someArg
```

[Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: Ok but if I do this, I cannot call function2 and function3 at once. I have to call them separately.